# Timeout with VNC connection from windows 7 to SLES10SP4

Tags: ssh, putty, vnc, suse

I'm having an issue establishing a VNC connecting to a SLES10SP 4 server using PuTTY on a Windows 7 workstation.

Remote Administration is enabled in YaST, as are all the other appropriate settings. Password Protection is disabled etc. Everything goes smoothly during configuration.

Then in PuTTY with the following settings:

Host Name (or IP address)

**Connection type:**

*SSH*

**Preferred SSH protocol version:**

*2 only*

**Forwarded ports:**

*4L6023   127.0.0.1:5901*

*Local*

*IPV4*

According to our documentation this configuration should work, but when I open the putty connection it simply times out. No errors, it just doesn't connect. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question title says that VNC is timing out. The question itself implies that Putty is timing out. What is timing out?

Comment: The putty connection. It gives no indication that it made any meaningful connection to the VNC server. When I select connect in putty it just hangs at a blank terminal screen indefinitely.

Comment: Timeout making an SSH connection usually means there's a firewall between your local host and the remote host. I'm guessing that's why you're trying to tunnel VNC through SSH in the first place--because you can't make a direct VNC connection to the remote host. Maybe you could explain a bit about the network between your local host and the remote one. Does your documentation tell you what specific ports are open through the firewall?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. We got it working. There was an issue with the way it was being configured on the remote host, specific to the depressingly old hardware we're working with. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got it working. There was an issue with the way it was being configured on the remote host, specific to the depressingly old hardware we're working with.